# Remove Preceding Characters in RegExp Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem sanitizing dynamic URLs e.g.

```
 var uri = '/localhost:8080////app//user/login.json?foo=bar';
 var sanitizedUri = uri.replace(/\.json*/, '');

 // print ==> /localhost:8080////app//user/login?foo=bar
```

What I want here is when "**.json**" is present in the URL,
I want to remove `.json` and succeeding characters (query params) and will only output the following:

```
/localhost:8080////app//user/login<br>
```

Note    `foo=bar` is a dynamic value.

Comment: (`n*` matches any number of `n`s.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding [`.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes)

> (The dot, the decimal point) matches any single character except line

to `RegExp` before [`*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers) to

> Matches the preceding item x 0 or more times.

following `\.json`

```js
var uri = '/localhost:8080////app//user/login.json?foo=bar';
var sanitizedUri = uri.replace(/\.json.*/, '');
console.log(sanitizedUri)
```